# Match all characters and redirect unless the string contains

Tags: regex, iis, web-config

I'm running several template based websites, using web.config on IIS to convert domain.com/somepage to domain.com/default.asp?page=somepage to include the correct files from a higher level directory. The rule I'm using looks like:

```
<rule name="friendly-urls">
    <match url="^[a-zA-Z0-9_]+" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" />
    <action type="Rewrite" url="default.asp?page={R:0}" />
</rule>
```

The problem is that each website also has a mobile version, available at domain.com/m/, and the way the redirection is set up right now, that address would redirect to domain.com/default.asp?page=m Somehow I need to make an exception for anything in the m/ directory, but I don't understand regular expressions or web.config well enough to accomplish this. I would be very appreciative if anyone could help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with web.config rules, but maybe this will work, or at least get you started:

```
<rule name="friendly-urls">
    <match url="^([a-zA-Z0-9_]+/)?([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)$" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" />
    <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:1}default.asp?page={R:2}" />
</rule>
```

The new Regex divides the input URL into an optional first match (which includes the forward slash) and a required second match. We want to prepend the first match to the output URL. If there is no first match (for non-mobile URLs), it should prepend an empty string. The second match is then appended to the output URL as usual.

Given "somepage", it should produce "default.asp?page=somepage"

Given "m/somepage", it should produce "m/default.asp?page=somepage"

I am unable to test anything but the Regex, but I hope this helps!